# Return something else other than NULL or EMPTY via mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to determine whether id is present or not in my MySQL table. If not I need to return -1 instead. So I tried `IFNULL`. However I am still getting empty.

```
select ifnull(id, -1) as id from docs  where id=3909090 LIMIT 1
```

I am supposed to get -1 here.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IFNULL()` this way

```
SELECT IFNULL( (select id from docs where id=3909090 LIMIT 1) ,-1) AS ID;
```

[***Demo on DB<>Fiddle***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e9bc57b94a277364e61d257ea10dc90c)

Comment: I eventually found this mistake in my query. Still thanks a lot for putting your effort :)

Comment: This is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this.

```
select -1 as id from docs where NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM docs WHERE id=3909090 )
```

`NOT EXISTS` will return True if a record is not found in the table with that id. Since `WHERE` condition is true it will print outer query value which is -1.

Comment: This will return a row for every row in the table

Answer (score 1):

You can `COUNT` the number of rows with `id = 3909090` and if 0, return `-1`, otherwise the `id` value:

```
select case when count(*) = 0 then -1
            else min(id)
       end as id
from docs  
where id = 3909090
```

Note we use `min(id)` to avoid issues with grouping.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c0bf917630da11838af14bcd681fe44a)